# How to apply a function to specific classes of objects in R

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe with variables of different class. I want to apply a function only to variables of class factor. How can I do that?

Comment: `lapply(data, function(x) if(is.factor(x)) foo(x) else x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
lapply(data, function(x) if(is.factor(x)) foo(x) else x)
```

Comment: That was too easy :-) . For homework, (corrado's . I know Andrie can do this),  modify the code so it rejects variables which are of class "factor" but also of some other class.

Comment: Ok, I feel quite stupid now, but I can't understand how to use that code. For example: my dataframe is "mydata" and I want to apply the function "describe" to all the variables of class factor in mydata. What would be the right syntax?